# from a class of 20 students, what is the mathematical expression for the number of ways of selecting at least 2 students

Tags: combinations

I thought that the simplest expression without using a calculator would be $20C2 +20C3+ 20C4 ... 20C20$. I then attempted to simplify to $21C3 + 21C5 + 21C7 + 21C9 + 21C11 + 21C13 + 21C15 + 21C17 + 21C19 + 20C20$ but I cannot seem to simply any further.
The answer in the book that I am using is 2<sup>20</sup>-21 but I'm not sure how they got this and how I should go about similar questions in the future. Thanks for any help

Comment: You can use the fact that $\sum_{i=0}^n {n \choose i}=2^n$

Comment: Have a look at the collection of subsets of the set of students (how much are there?). Then discard the subsets with less than 2 students.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the *complement*, ie from total ways of selection, subtract ways where $20,19,$ students are *rejected*

Since each student can either be selected or rejected, there are a total of $2^{20}$ possible selections.

From this we subtract $\binom{20}{20} + \binom{20}{19} = 21$